# Ionic 1 deploy service progress bar

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i implemented the deploy service to my ionic app (i am using ionic 1) and it is working fine, now i want to show the users the time remaining for the download or maybe a progress bar so they do not think that the app is freezing.
below is the function of the deploy

```
var deployFunction = function() {
        $ionicDeploy.check().then(function(snapshotAvailable){

            if (snapshotAvailable) {
            // When snapshotAvailable is true, you can apply the snapshot
                MainService.startSpinner("Downloading Updates");//this shows a loading image indicating that the download started

                //applying the snapshot
                $ionicDeploy.download()
                .then(
                    function() {
                        MainService.stopSpinner();
                        MainService.startSpinner("Extracting");
                        $ionicDeploy.extract()
                        .then(
                            function(){
                                MainService.stopSpinner();
                                $ionicDeploy.load();
                            }, function(error) {
                                console.log("ERROR EXTRACT "+error);
                                // Error extracting
                            }, function(progress) {
                                // progress of extracting
                                console.log('extraction progress '+progress);
                            }
                        );
                    }, function(error){
                        //download error
                        console.log("ERROR Downloading "+error);
                    }, function(progress) {
                        //download progress 
                        console.log('download progress '+progress);
                    }
                );
            }
        });
    }
```

i've read somewhere that the progress function should return an integer...
but it is not and i have no idea how to get information about the download beside that it is started or it is finished. 
any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for future references this was solved based on [this](https://docs.ionic.io/api/client/deploydownloadoptions/) documentation, the code will be

```
$ionicDeploy.download({
                    onProgress: function(p) {
                        console.log(p);
                    }
                })
                .then(
                    function() {...
```

i tried it and the console logged numbers from 1 to 100 indicating the download progress.